# requestAnimationFrame too fast

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, ecmascript-6

I am creating simple animation in canvas. I use requestanimationframe to control animation. There is 3 circle. But i can only see 3 circle and animation is too fast. My question is how can i slow my animation and how can show each frame. here is my live [link](http://codepen.io/marmikdesai/pen/bWOjwj?editors=0010).

```
const swing = (time) => {
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    circle[i] = new ball();
    circle[i].draw(i, circle[i].color);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(swing);
}

requestAnimationFrame(swing);
//swing();


function ball(i){
    this.x = random(100, 150);
    this.y = random(40, 60);
    this.radius = 45;
    this.color = getRandomColor(random(1, 30));
    this.strokeText = "m"  

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
    this.draw = function(i, color){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.font="30px Verdana";
        ctx.arc(i*this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        ctx.strokeText(i,i*this.x,this.y);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edited:- I am creating something similar like this:- http://codepen.io/jscottsmith/pen/oWyxjp?editors=1010

Comment: What is the animation supposed to be?

Comment: @李骏骁 something similar this http://codepen.io/jscottsmith/pen/oWyxjp?editors=1010

Comment: It seems that every frame of your animation will be drawn randomly, as a result, there will be no trasition effect but only instant position switch.
And in requestAnimationFrame callback function, I think you will need to control the speed by evaluating based on time.

Comment: can you tell me how?

Comment: Just added one simple example~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple example, let three balls doing some circular motion:

```js
// refer below 
// http://codepen.io/jscottsmith/pen/oWyxjp?editors=1010
const el = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      ctx = el.getContext('2d');
      let circle = [];
el.width = document.body.clientWidth;
el.height = document.body.clientHeight;

const getRandomColor = (i) => {
  let count = 30,
      color = 1,
      hue = (i / count * color) * 360;
  return `hsla(${hue}, 100%, 50%, 1)`
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  circle[i] = new ball();
}

let angle = 0;
let speed = 0.02;
  
const swing = (time) => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, el.width, el.height);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    circle[i].x = circle[i].x + Math.cos(angle) * 1;
    circle[i].y = circle[i].y + Math.sin(angle) * 2;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
    circle[i].draw(i, circle[i].color);
  }
  angle += speed;
  requestAnimationFrame(swing);
}

requestAnimationFrame(swing);
//swing();


function ball(i){
    this.x = random(100, 150);
    this.y = random(40, 60);
    this.radius = 45;
    this.color = getRandomColor(random(1, 30));
    this.strokeText = "m"  
  
    this.draw = function(i, color){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.font="30px Verdana";
        ctx.arc(i*this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        ctx.strokeText(i,i*this.x,this.y);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}

function random (num1, num2) {
    var max = Math.max(num1, num2);
    var min = Math.min(num1, num2);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```